# How to resolve error unfunc 'isfinite' in order to create a seasonal statsmodels in python?

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter, statsmodels, forecasting

I am trying to create an ARIMA model to forecast however I am getting an error that says

> "ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs
>   could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the
>   casting rule ''safe''"

I am trying to run the code:

```
Data= pd.read_csv(xcjs_2018.csv', low_memory=False) 
Data['day'] = pd.to_datetime(Data['day']) 

from plotly.plotly import plot_mpl from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal
import seasonal_decompose 
result = seasonal_decompose(Data, model= 'multiplicative') 
fig = result.plot()
plot_mpl(fig)
```

My Dataframe looks like this:

```
Date        Name      COUNT
2018-08-03  XCJS_22   199
2018-08-04  XCJS_22   200
2018-08-06  XCJS_22   151
2018-08-07  XCJS_22   159
2018-08-08  XCJS_22   451
2018-08-15  XCJS_22   217
2018-08-20  XCJS_22   389
```

[Traceback error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C81H8.png)
Would anyone know how to help?

Comment: Could you show us the traceback?

Comment: @Mirac7 have added a picture into the question of the traceback error I get when running

Comment: Hi, pls show us your code on how you load the data into Data (dataframe). Thanks.

Comment: I tried to clarify your code.  The error occurs in `seasonal_decompose`.  I have no idea what that is, or what inputs in requires.  Evidently it can't handle your dataframe.  The error suggests that it expects a numpy array, not a dataframe.

Comment: Would anyone happen to know if there are any other forecasting methods I could use with my type of dataframe instead of ARIMA if it won't work?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the date column as index and plot Data['Count'] column with freq=1.

```
#reads csv file
Data= pd.read_csv(xcjs_2018.csv', low_memory=False) 
Data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Data['Date'])
Data = Data.set_index('Date')

#Plot it
from plotly.plotly import plot_mpl 
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose 
result = seasonal_decompose(Data.COUNT, model= 'multiplicative', freq=1) 
fig = result.plot()
plot_mpl(fig)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help however I still get an error message after running this - 'PlotlyRequestError: No message' is what comes up when I run the code